# Laravel Auth::guard only working for default

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, guard

First time i've asked anything on here before and not the most experienced so please be nice!

I have two tables set up in my DB - Users & Agents.

I have tried multiple ways in which to login both of the users and would ideally like them to be able to login from the same form and do a check on both guards to see if the credentials are valid but for some reason when doing doing attempts on the guards it will only work for the table my default is set to in my auth.php file.

Guards I am attempting:

```
Auth::guard('web')->attempt($credentials)

Auth::guard('agent')->attempt($credentials)
```

If I set my default guard in my `auth.php` file to the web guard its works fine and logs in the matching credentials from the Users table but when trying the agents credentials it shows in my network tab:

Login -

> POST 302 found

Agent -

> GET 302 found

Login -

> Get 200 OK

So it's almost like it acknowledges to credentials are correct and re-directs but then doesnt carry on using the selected guard?

[LoginController - DoLogin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7b84.png)

[Auth.php configeration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duavJ.png)

Comment: please check updated asnwer

Comment: Have you looked into [Laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) at all? Could help you simplify the logic component here.

Answer (score 0):

in your `config/auth.php` copy below code :

```
<?php
return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'agent' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'agents',
        ]

    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'agents' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Agent::class,
        ]
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'agents' => [
            'provider' => 'agents',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
];
```

in your Login Controller :

```
 public function login(Request $request)
    {
      $this->validate($request, [
        'email'   => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
      ]);

      if (Auth::guard('agent')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
        return redirect('/dashboard/agent');
      }

      if(Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])){
         return redirect('/dashboard/user');
      }

        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->input());


    }
```

Comment: I get the same issue. It goes to 302 then back to 200

Comment: It seems to authenticate the user with the credentials then be reverted back to the login :/

Comment: Thanks for the response but unfortunately still no luck when trying to log in the agents :(

Comment: create 2 separate login controller for user and agents

Comment: I had two before then combined it into one and was still having the same isssue